# Pearson r with percentages across time

Tags: r, epidemiology, pearson-r

Data sources: CDC National Survey of Family Growth, CDC vital stats.
Population: American women aged 15-44 in 1982, 95, 2002, 2006
Sample sizes: several thousand

Can I use Pearson r to show linear correlation between two percentage variables? That is, how % of American women who do X correlates with a percentage of events that are categorized a certain way? An example would be percent of Americans who report having driven drunk in the past month in various years compared to percent of motor vehicle collisions that were alcohol-related in same years. The sample is not the same over time but the population almost is, except that it's within an age range so for example the women who were 44 in 1982 will not be included in 1995 and so on.

The reason I want to use percent is because the numbers from the 2 arms of the CDC don't exactly correspond. The National Survey of Family Growth asks women in the survey about births that they have experienced within the past 5 years and applies that to the whole American population, and that number is similar, but not identical, to the number of actual recorded births in the appropriate 5 year interval in the CDC Vital Statistics. I want to combine data from both sources into one aggregate category. Is that possible?